# How bash processes pipes and redirections

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm studying about pipes and redirects in Bash and came across a situation i can't find an explanation about how bash processes its pipes and redirects.

I was testing this command:

```
cat << EOF > arquivo.txt |  wc -l < arquivo.txt > linhas.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
```

And i was expecting it to give the output of **2** because it should have added to arquivo.txt file the user the text

> ola
> ola1

And should have added to linhas.txt the output of **wc -l < arquivo.txt** witch should have been **2** but instead of that the output of the command it's **0** and if i execute the commands separately without the pipes its working as it should.

I couldn't find any explanation online about it and want to know more about how bash parses and executes the pipes as my only theory is that the pipes are executed independently and not caring about if the commands before the pipe were executed completely witch its a bit counterintuitive for me.
Is that the truth or am I missing something?

Comment: Each process can only have one stdin source; it can be a pipe _or_ a redirection, but FD 0 can only be connected to one thing.

Comment: As another demonstration, try running `cat <foo.txt <bar.txt` -- you'll see that only `bar.txt` is connected to the stdin of `cat`, _because that's what was left after all the redirections were performed_; the shell _first_ connected `foo.txt` to the stdin of the subshell that will be later replaced with `cat`, _then_ replaced that with a connection to `bar.txt`, _then_ -- having completed all redirections and pipeline setup -- invokes `execve()` and thereby actually replaces that subshell with a copy of `cat`; by the time `cat` starts, only `bar.txt` is connected to its stdin.

Comment: An important aspect of this is that wiring up stdin/stdout/stderr is done during pipeline setup; by the time the pipeline is _actually running_ (and note that all parts run in parallel), the subshells that were responsible for doing the setup are replaced with the actual processes being run, so the shell no longer has any ability to change the wiring; your pipe operators and redirections specify what to do _before_ starting `cat` or `wc`.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find any explanation online about it and want to know more
> about how bash parses and executes the pipes as my only theory is that
> the pipes are executed independently and not caring about if the
> commands before the pipe were executed completely witch its a bit
> counterintuitive for me.
>  Is that the truth or am I missing something?

You have only one pipe, so I guess you are hypothesizing that the *commands* on the two ends of a pipe may be executed independently.  Yes, they are (mostly).  The idea is that they run at the same time, with the standard output of the command on the left fed into the standard input of the one on the right.

That the one command reads the output of the other ordinarily creates some synchronization between the two, but **you have suppressed that** by overriding the pipe with redirections inside the commands on both ends.  Per [the POSIX specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02) for the shell language,

> The standard output of `command1` shall be connected to the standard input of `command2`. **The standard input, standard output, or both of a command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline before any redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the command**

(Emphasis added).

The Bash manual contains [similar text](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html), but it is unclear about the ordering with respect to the redirections of the second command.

If you want one command to run to completion before the other starts, without connecting their standard streams, then just run one after the other, without a pipeline:

```
cat << EOF > arquivo.txt
ola
ola1
EOF

wc -l < arquivo.txt > linhas.txt

# OR

cat << EOF > arquivo.txt ; wc -l < arquivo.txt > linhas.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
```

If you want to use a pipeline to convey `cat`'s output to `wc`, then drop the redirections that are getting in the way of that:

```
cat << EOF | wc -l > linhas.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
```

That does result in `arquivo.txt` not being written, however.  If you want to write `arquivo.txt` too then use `tee` instead of `cat` (or insert a `tee` command into the pipeline between `cat` and `wc`):

```
tee arquivo.txt << EOF | wc -l > linhas.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it.

Try using `tee` to write the pipe's contents to an intermediate file and re-echo the piped lines*:

```bash
cat << EOF | tee arquivo.txt | wc -l > linhas.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
```

Each program after the pipe will receive the full list. However if you were to add another pipe and program after `wc` instead of redirecting to the file, it would only receive one line containing `2`.

You can also break up your commands into two commands, the first to create `arquivo.txt` and the second to create `linhas.txt`:

```bash
cat << EOF > arquivo.txt
ola
ola1
EOF
wc -l < arquivo.txt > linhas.txt
```

Notes:

* Yes, I'm aware this is a Useless Use of Cat (UUOC).